# Grails - Ambiguous method overloading for method java.io.File#<init>

Tags: tomcat, grails

I am trying to run Grails 3.0.11 with tomcat8.

The JDK version is 1.8.0_77, and environment variable - "JAVA_HOME" and "PATH" were rightly set.

When I startup tomcat, I got this:

```
2017-02-21 10:51:08,013 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR grails.boot.GrailsApp - Application startup failed
groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: Ambiguous method overloading for method java.io.File#<init>.
Cannot resolve which method to invoke for [null, class java.lang.String] due to overlapping prototypes between:
        [class java.lang.String, class java.lang.String]
        [class java.io.File, class java.lang.String]
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.chooseMostSpecificParams(MetaClassImpl.java:3241) ~[groovy-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.chooseMethodInternal(MetaClassImpl.java:3194) ~[groovy-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.chooseMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:3137) ~[groovy-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.createConstructorSite(MetaClassImpl.java:3431) ~[groovy-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.createCallConstructorSite(CallSiteArray.java:91) ~[groovy-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallConstructor(CallSiteArray.java:60) ~[groovy-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:235) ~[groovy-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:255) ~[groovy-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
        at asset.pipeline.AssetPipelineGrailsPlugin$_doWithSpring_closure2.doCall(AssetPipelineGrailsPlugin.groovy:101) ~[asset-pipeline-grails-2.8.2.jar:na]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_77]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_77]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_77]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_77]
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93) ~[groovy-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
        at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325) ~[groovy-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:294) ~[groovy-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1019) ~[groovy-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
        at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:426) ~[groovy-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
        at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:420) ~[groovy-2.4.5.jar:2.4.5]
        at grails.spring.BeanBuilder.invokeBeanDefiningClosure(BeanBuilder.java:758) ~[grails-spring-3.0.11.jar:3.0.11]
        at grails.spring.BeanBuilder.beans(BeanBuilder.java:588) ~[grails-spring-3.0.11.jar:3.0.11]
        at grails.spring.BeanBuilder.invokeMethod(BeanBuilder.java:531) ~[grails-spring-3.0.11.jar:3.0.11]
        at org.grails.plugins.DefaultGrailsPlugin.doWithRuntimeConfiguration(DefaultGrailsPlugin.java:559) ~[grails-core-3.0.11.jar:3.0.11]
        at org.grails.plugins.AbstractGrailsPluginManager.doRuntimeConfiguration(AbstractGrailsPluginManager.java:172) ~[grails-core-3.0.11.jar:3.0.11]
        at grails.boot.config.GrailsApplicationPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(GrailsApplicationPostProcessor.groovy:157) ~[grails-core-3.0.11.jar:3.0.11]
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:119) ~[spring-context-4.1.8.RELEASE.jar:4.1.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:607) ~[spring-context-4.1.8.RELEASE.jar:4.1.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:462) ~[spring-context-4.1.8.RELEASE.jar:4.1.8.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:117) ~[spring-boot-1.2.7.RELEASE.jar:1.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:689) ~[spring-boot-1.2.7.RELEASE.jar:1.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:321) ~[spring-boot-1.2.7.RELEASE.jar:1.2.7.RELEASE]
        at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:51) [grails-core-3.0.11.jar:3.0.11]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:134) [spring-boot-1.2.7.RELEASE.jar:1.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.grails.boot.context.web.GrailsAppServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(GrailsAppServletInitializer.groovy:57) [grails-web-boot-3.0.11.jar:3.0.11]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:81) [spring-boot-1.2.7.RELEASE.jar:1.2.7.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:175) [spring-web-4.1.8.RELEASE.jar:4.1.8.RELEASE]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5240) [catalina.jar:8.0.33]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147) [catalina.jar:8.0.33]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:725) [catalina.jar:8.0.33]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701) [catalina.jar:8.0.33]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717) [catalina.jar:8.0.33]
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1092) [catalina.jar:8.0.33]
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1834) [catalina.jar:8.0.33]
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) [na:1.8.0_77]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) [na:1.8.0_77]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [na:1.8.0_77]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [na:1.8.0_77]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_77]
21-Feb-2017 10:51:08.019 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal ContainerBase.addChild: start: 
 org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/cdkey]]
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:153)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:725)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1092)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1834)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: groovy.lang.GroovyRuntimeException: Ambiguous method overloading for method java.io.File#<init>.
Cannot resolve which method to invoke for [null, class java.lang.String] due to overlapping prototypes between:
        [class java.lang.String, class java.lang.String]
        [class java.io.File, class java.lang.String]
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.chooseMostSpecificParams(MetaClassImpl.java:3241)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.chooseMethodInternal(MetaClassImpl.java:3194)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.chooseMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:3137)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.createConstructorSite(MetaClassImpl.java:3431)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.createCallConstructorSite(CallSiteArray.java:91)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallConstructor(CallSiteArray.java:60)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:235)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callConstructor(AbstractCallSite.java:255)
        at asset.pipeline.AssetPipelineGrailsPlugin$_doWithSpring_closure2.doCall(AssetPipelineGrailsPlugin.groovy:101)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
        at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:294)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1019)
        at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:426)
        at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:420)
        at grails.spring.BeanBuilder.invokeBeanDefiningClosure(BeanBuilder.java:758)
        at grails.spring.BeanBuilder.beans(BeanBuilder.java:588)
        at grails.spring.BeanBuilder.invokeMethod(BeanBuilder.java:531)
        at org.grails.plugins.DefaultGrailsPlugin.doWithRuntimeConfiguration(DefaultGrailsPlugin.java:559)
        at org.grails.plugins.AbstractGrailsPluginManager.doRuntimeConfiguration(AbstractGrailsPluginManager.java:172)
        at grails.boot.config.GrailsApplicationPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(GrailsApplicationPostProcessor.groovy:157)
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:119)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:607)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:462)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:117)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:689)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:321)
        at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:51)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:134)
        at org.grails.boot.context.web.GrailsAppServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(GrailsAppServletInitializer.groovy:57)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.web.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:81)
        at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:175)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5240)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
        ... 10 more

21-Feb-2017 10:51:08.021 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Error deploying web application directory /data/tomcat8080/webapps/cdkey
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/cdkey]]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:729)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory(HostConfig.java:1092)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDirectory.run(HostConfig.java:1834)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Do you have a bean that creates a java.io.File object with 2 arguments the first of which could be a String or a File and the 2nd is a String? The first argument is null so groovy doesn't know which constructor to use to created the File.

Comment: No. I checked my code. I never create any java.io.File objects. The project is running well in IDE idea, but when I running it with tomcat, the exception happens.

Comment: @MikeW Thanks for you remind. It caused by a plugin that may have some bugs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is caused by plugin "org.grails.plugins:asset-pipeline".

Upgrade the plugin to:

runtime "com.bertramlabs.plugins:asset-pipeline-grails:2.13.1"